# No shadow on absolutely positioned View/Image?

Tags: android, css, react-native, shadow, absolute

I did a materalistic designed "Add" button on my **Android-primary** react-native app. While I used `elevation` style property as a primary source for shadows in the rest of the elements, I've discovered that it stops working when applied to an `absolute` positioned element. (Which I partially understand probably because absolutely positioned element ignores the general layout rules, but still, a shadow should work).
As far as I know, Android gets `elevation` and iOS gets their respective shadow properties.

I'd like to have this:

[image]

but I 'm getting no shadow once I set the element's style as absolute (in the bottom right corner).

Am I missing something or is it not working yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, there is no current shadow support for Android in React Native yet and I think you are on the right track to use elevation way to achieve this. But it should only work for Android 5.0 or above.

Alternatively, you can try this module (https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow). It works for me.

Comment: Thanks, the module helps, although the implementation is more complicated that it should be but better something than nothing :) luckily my app will support api 21+ so it should work everywhere.